# Composer Install - Class 'Acme\BackendServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Attempt to install Laravel 4.2 project failed with the following output:

```
user@machine /project $ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Acme\Modules\Account\AccountServiceProvider' not found in /project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Acme\\Modules\\Account\\AccountServiceProvider' not found","file":"\/project\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php","line":157}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Acme\Modules\Account\AccountServiceProvider' not found in /project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 15  
  7
```

Here are the providers that seem to be failing from `app/config/app.php`:

```
'Acme\BackendServiceProvider',
'Acme\Modules\Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProvider',
'Acme\Modules\Account\AccountServiceProvider',
'Acme\Modules\Payment\PaymentServiceProvider',
'Acme\Modules\MerchantAccount\MerchantAccountServiceProvider',
```

Here is the autoload part from composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Acme/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\": "app/Acme"
    }
},
```

Any idea what this error means and how I can fix it?

Comment: delete vendor folder and run composer install

Comment: Still fails. Installs everything, then outputs: `Generating autoload files...php artisan clear-compiled...PHP Fatal error:...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9678).

---

You have to manually remove the `compiled.php` file:

```
rm bootstrap/compiled.php
```

After this, you should be able to run `composer update` properly.

Comment: That file hasn't yet been created. The truth is it won't composer install either, producing an identical error

Comment: @MonOve - Does the `Acme\Modules\Account\AccountServiceProvider` actually exist?